# How to send multiple parameters on a API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, rest

I have this user search function that adds a parameter to the router and calls the API. It only sends a single param, username. But now I want to send firstName, lastName and email removing username in the search function. I have a backend API with this structure:

```
var searchResult = repo.Search(
username: query.username,
firstName: query.firstName,
lastName: query.lastName,
email: query.email);
```

The way I am calling username now is with something like this:

```
    onSearch = () => {
        if (this.state.searchValue) {
            this.context.queryUpdater.addParam('username', this.state.searchValue);
        } else {
            this.context.queryUpdater.removeParam('username');
        }
    };
```

addParam and removeParam removes the params from the router and URL. I have tried adding three params like below, but it did not work the way it was supposed to, it calls all the field but does not works, it updates the router to `/users?firstName=first&lastName=first&email=first` but only shows the results for `firstName`

```
       if (this.state.searchValue) {
        this.context.queryUpdater.addParam('firstName', this.state.searchValue);
            this.context.queryUpdater.addParam('lastName', this.state.searchValue);
            this.context.queryUpdater.addParam('email', this.state.searchValue);
        } else {
            this.context.queryUpdater.removeParam('firstName');
            this.context.queryUpdater.removeParam('lastName');
            this.context.queryUpdater.removeParam('email');
        }
```

And the search input is broken too,

```
    updateFilterState = options => {
        this.setState({
            searchValue: options.firstName || options.lastName || options.email || '',
        });
    };
```

It was only `options.username` so I added those three. But now, every time I hit        backspace and clear the field it displays the same value with removing the last character, for example : `hello` and I clear the field `hell` comes back.

I hope this can help you understand a little, or still maybe difficult to understand the whole issue but any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Usually if i’m searching there is a single text box where i can input the text i’m looking for and that single field is sent to the server, which then searches all the necessary database fields (first name last name etc) for the text i entered.  I don’t understand your approach with three different input fields.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @James. I came to a solution like yours where I need to update the backend API, which will take a single query and goes through the fields.